# No-IP DDNS to My Domain - What DNS Records Do I Have To Add?

Tags: domain, nameserver, a-record, ddns

I have a DDNS set up at "example.ddns.net", which is a fixed address I can always find my own server at - but I can't seem to link it with my domain name. I'm using the domain name providers own nameservers - and I can get to a DNS management page which allows to add records like:

A, AAAA, C NAME ,LOC ,MX ,NAPTR ,RP ,TXT

Then give them a name, choose the TTL (defaulted at 14440) and input a target.

I've tried creating an A Record and using "example.ddns.net" as the target, but it wants an IP address...

I'm obviously barking up the wrong tree, would somebody be able to tell me what I need to do to get my domain linked up with my DDNS address... Or is it impossible to do this?

Many thanks, and sorry if the question is rather basic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create CNAME entry. Like this:

```
yourdomain.tld CNAME example.ddns.net
```

Comment: @UnluckyForSome so why you not mark my answer as solution?

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this :-) think i've done it now.